# Spring boot 2.1 run on Ubuntu18.4, but can not connect from outside

Tags: linux, spring-boot, ubuntu, networking

My main computer is Windows10.
I'm trying to execute my spring boot project on VM Ubuntu18.04.
In Ubuntu, I can connect my spring boot project.

```
root@ubuntu:~# netstat -tnlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      691/systemd-resolve
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      909/sshd
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          :::*                    LISTEN      8513/java
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      909/sshd
```

```
root@ubuntu:~# curl localhost:8080
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
...
```

But I cannot access my spring boot on VM Ubuntu using browser.
I'm using same network

```
root@ubuntu:~# ifconfig
enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.56.103  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.56.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe9b:9f58  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:9b:9f:58  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 337554  bytes 470268104 (470.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 32494  bytes 6910341 (6.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I think the problem is **tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          :::*                    LISTEN      8513/java** on `netstat -tnlp`

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8080
  address: 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: Is your browser running in the VM or on Windows?

Comment: My browser is running in Windows.

Comment: So you have to figure out what's the IP address of the VM

Comment: I set up static ip on Ubuntu using NAT, Host only. I can access Ubuntu(192.168.56.103) using ssh on my Windows. but I cannot connect my web service running on VM Ubuntu at Windows.

Comment: how do you run the app? Can you try to start it with java -jar <your>.jar -Dserver.address=0.0.0.0

Comment: Yes, but it still working by tcp6 0 0 127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: I just start using the command (java -jar app.jar -Dserver.address=0.0.0.0).